# Mercurial error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: windows, mercurial

I'm getting the following error when I try to update my Mercurial directory on a PC:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Other comments have noted that the problem lies with having ampersands or carets in the path. However my path is this:

```
C:\Users\First Last\Desktop\goodmorningcmc
```

That doesn't have any ampersands.

Is it possible that the error is being caused by the space in my username? This is a really frustrating error.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: This sounds like something that needs debugging -- it's much easier to help you if you would write to your mailinglist (mercurial@selenic.com) or drop by our IRC channel (http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=mercurial)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem - it turns out there was a filename in the repo that contained a pipe character `|` . Renaming that file solved the problem.

Comment: What process did you go through to find the file?

Comment: My friend was working on the (un-updated) repo and I noticed one of the folders had about 40 files missing. Checking the folder contents revealed the missing file. I tested it by renaming the file, committing and pushing the repo.

Answer (score 5):

I could be that a file has been added to the repository by someone else which has dodgy character in it. When running update Mercurial is trying to create the file on disk. Try running `hg serve` and browsing to http://localhost:8000 - then look through the changeset history to see which files have been added/renamed. That might give you a clue.